# How does Flink window trigger computation immediately

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev5Bt.png)
I have a real-time data warehouse scene, FLink one-minute window for index aggregation, the aggregated data will be sent to kafka, downstream Flink task will conduct secondary aggregation of index data, how to design can accelerate downstream Flink task trigger calculation, rather than wait for the next minute data to trigger calculation

I think of the solution is to customize the window, in flink each Slot for key aggregation, using map storage, when the window is over, the data in the specified Slot will be sent to the downstream kafka designated partition, after the data is sent to the partition to send an end mark, downstream Flink task after receiving the end mark trigger calculation,
However, the code implementation of this scheme is complicated, and the event time and window need to be realized by ourselves. Therefore, I would like to consult whether there is an immediate mechanism to trigger calculation when using flink window in the real-time counting warehouse scenario

Comment: If the only consumer of the initial one -minute aggregation is the second Flink workflow, then why are you using Kafka as a bridge between the two aggregations?

Comment: @kkrugler Thanks for your answer, the above is a relatively simple example, there may be multiple Flink consumption aggregated data downstream, and it is not possible to combine multiple Flink tasks into one

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're trying to do here. If you have a window operator that calculates an aggregation, and you have multiple downstream independent Flink workflows that rely on the aggregation result, then how would you avoid waiting for the result to be generated? Until the 1 minute window is over, you don't have a usable aggregation, yes?